# MySQL Update problem

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result=mysql_query(" UPDATE xxxxxx_users SET User_Password='$Password' WHERE FstName='$First' AND LstName='$Last'",$db)  or die ("Password update successful!");
echo "Update failed, unknown user";
```

This correctly updates the db when the first and last names match and the db is not affected when they don't.   My only issue is I always display the Update failed, unknown user message.  what did I do wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) function returns true when an SQL query is successful:

> For other type of SQL statements,
> INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
> mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
> or FALSE on error.

Your code is assuming that the query returns the number of rows effected. Use the [mysql_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function for this purpose:

```
$result=mysql_query(" UPDATE xxxxxx_users SET User_Password='$Password' WHERE FstName='$First' AND LstName='$Last'",$db)
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
  die ("Password update successful!");
else
  echo "Update failed, unknown user";
```

Comment: Keep in mind that mysql_affected_rows only returns a value > 0 if data was actually changed. E.g. if you have a record ('firstname', 'lastname', 'xyz') you will get `0` for `UPDATE foo SET User_Password='xyz' WHERE FstName='firstname' AND LstName='lastname'` although there is a record matching the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do this the other way round...

```
$result=mysql_query(" UPDATE xxxxxx_users SET User_Password='$Password' WHERE FstName='$First' AND LstName='$Last'",$db)
     or die ("Update failed, unknown user"); 

echo "Password update successful!";
```

Comment: All that did was give me the "password update successful" message regardless of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part (mysql_query) evaluates to true, there is no need to evaluate the second or part (die). You can use and instead.

And, please, read about SQL Injections.

A suggestion to your coding style:

Something like this:

```
if ($result)
   ...success
else 
   ...fail
```

is much more readable.